# Why is my workflow triggering when previous fail?

Tags: github-actions

I have two workflow. Workflow A and B. I want to trigger workflow B only when workflow A is completed. But when workflow A fail, workflow B is being triggered?

My workflow A:

```
name: Security

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Bygg og test"]
    types:
      - completed
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 3 * * *'
```

My workflow B:

```
name: Deploy dev og prod

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Security"]
    types:
      - completed

env:
  IMAGE: ghcr.io/${{ github.repository }}:${{ github.sha }}

jobs:
  deploy-dev-gcp:
    name: Deploy til dev-gcp
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: nais/deploy/actions/deploy@v1
        env:
          APIKEY: ${{ secrets.NAIS_DEPLOY_APIKEY }}
          CLUSTER: dev-gcp
          RESOURCE: .nais/naiserator.yaml
          VARS: .nais/dev-gcp.json
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Note that the action `actions/checkout` is available in `v3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-based-on-the-conclusion-of-another-workflow), the `workflow_run` trigger invokes a workflow regardless of the conclusion of the other workflow.

Therefore, if you want your workflow to only run if the other one ran successfully, add this condition:

```yaml
if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'
```

In your case:

```yaml
# ...
jobs:
  deploy-dev-gcp:
    name: Deploy til dev-gcp
    if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' && (github.ref == 'refs/heads/dev' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/master')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
# etc..
```