# Any workaround for github actions workflow_run.conclusion randomly failing?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm using `workflow_run.conclusion` to send workflow notifications as per [github docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-based-on-the-conclusion-of-another-workflow).

The problem is that it randomly doesn't match the `success` status, I don't understand what's happening, or how to get more info about this.

Let me give you an example:

There's an workflow that builds an API and then the notification job triggers based on its completion. This is the step from the notification job:

```
    steps:
      - name: Send slack notification on success
        if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' }}
        env:
          GIT_BRANCH: ${{ needs.get_envs.outputs.GIT_BRANCH }}
          GIT_SHA_SHORT: ${{ needs.get_envs.outputs.GIT_SHA_SHORT }}
          GIT_MESSAGE: ${{ needs.get_envs.outputs.GIT_MESSAGE }}
        id: success
        run: |
          slack_message_text="${WORKFLOW_NAME} | ${WORKFLOW_RUN_CONCLUSION}"
[other run actions -- redacted]
```

now, the build workflow finished successfully
[image: workflow exit status success]
and triggers the notification workflow based on completion:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows:
      - Deploy API Backend
    types:
      - completed
    branches:
      - master
```

which runs, but randomly (and this is very annoying) doesn't match the completion exit status of the workflow triggering it. In this case the job successfully finished, and has a `Successful` status, but github actions didn't match `success` and ignored the step :(

[image: ignore success]

This only happens randomly. It matches the success status most of the time, and works as expected:

[image: expected run on success]

Could this be a case sensitive issue, did anyone else get this?
Any workaround advice?

L.E. it looks like `github.event.workflow_run.conclusion` randomly returns an empty string, and the match fails. Does anyone knows why would this be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my workflow triggering when previous fail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72884110/why-is-my-workflow-triggering-when-previous-fail)

Comment: no, because in my case github.event.workflow_run.conclusion comes up as an empty string, and doesn't match the condition  `if: github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success'`

Comment: seems this is a bug on github side, and it's not consistent (most of the time works fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

github support said this is an issue on their end, due to a delay updating conclusion so it remains `"conclusion": null,` and a temporary workaround is to refactor and query for wf run results at a later time, using https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs#list-workflow-runs

Comment: Is there an issue for this, or where did you get this update? I'd like to follow along if possible

Comment: they didn't mention any open issues, just that it's in progress w/out any eta.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me to call the list later on. This needs to be reactive. As an example, looking for failed WF and sending notifications ASAP, without adding too many steps if possible