# GitHub workflow_run.conclusion now randomly returns an empty string even when successful

Tags: github-actions

Starting last week, on the 21st of July, my GitHub workflow's `github.event.workflow_run.conclusion` started to return an empty string randomly (maybe a third of the times), and wasn't doing so before.

I'm using a GitHub action to send a notification when a workflow failed. To do this, I have something like so:

```
on:
  workflow_run:
    # List of workflows where a failure would trigger notifications
    workflows:
      - "This Workflow"
      - "That Workflow"
    branches: [main]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  notification:
    if: github.event_name == 'workflow_run' && github.event.workflow_run.conclusion != 'success'
    ... -> send a notification
```

The notification started to trigger for workflows with a success last week, so I've outputted the `conclusion`, and it seems that it's now sometimes an empty string, even though it says "success" on the GitHub Actions' page.

Any idea on what changed on the GitHub side? I'm not seeing any relevant recent changes in the documentation.

---

**Note**: [Here's the doc](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-a-workflow-based-on-the-conclusion-of-another-workflow) I used to create this action.

**Second note**: An empty string is not even a possible choice of the enum for "conclusion", according to the official documentation, which states that it [can be one of: action_required, cancelled, failure, neutral, success, skipped, stale, timed_out](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/checks/runs#create-a-check-run)

Comment: I'm seeing this too. I run the chain of jobs several times, and it works 1/3 times. I also think it's a relatively new problem.

Comment: I found some people talking about the problem here: https://github.com/community/community/discussions/21090

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any workaround for github actions workflow\_run.conclusion randomly failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73107307/any-workaround-for-github-actions-workflow-run-conclusion-randomly-failing)

Comment: Thanks @DavidS, I'll put one of the temporary workarounds proposed in the thread you posted here, as a temporary solution until a real one fixes this problem

Comment: @rethab, it's a similar question based on the same fundamental problem, but it doesn't answer my question (nothing on the internet seems to answer it as of right now), but thanks for looking it up, I had not found this one. I'll follow it just in case

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a **temporary workaround** (*this is not a definitive answer*), which was found on the link provided by @DavidS, from a discussion on the GitHub community forums ([here is the link](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/21090#discussioncomment-3226271)).

> shreecodes: As a workaround, we added a job to our workflows that are triggered by the workflow_run event. The octokit/request-action makes this relatively straight-forward:

```
  get_workflow_conclusion:
    name: Lookup Conclusion of Workflow_Run Event
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      conclusion: ${{ fromJson(steps.get_conclusion.outputs.data).conclusion }}
    steps:
      - name: Get Workflow Run
        uses: octokit/request-action@v2.1.0
        id: get_conclusion
        with:
          route: GET /repos/${{ github.repository }}/actions/runs/${{ github.event.workflow_run.id }}
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Still doesn't answer why it stopped working as expected, and still not a real fix for the problem, but can at least be used as a workaround until then.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `failure() &&` as github requires this when including extra conditions for a step to run after a failure. This is to override the default status check of success() that is automatically applied to if conditions that don't contain a status check function.

Thus update it to:

```
jobs:
  notification:
    if: ${{ failure() && github.event_name == 'workflow_run' && github.event.workflow_run.conclusion != 'success' }}
    ... -> send a notification
```

This is explained in [Github - failure with conditions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#failure-with-conditions)